# How to get all prices in cart?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components Cart and CartItem.
i need to take all prices in state "total" of CartItem in Cart.
But when CartItems rendering in map, they rewrite the state and get only last price of list .

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {CartItem} from './CartItem'
import './Cart.scss'

export const Cart = ({cart, setCart, count, setCount}) => {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className='cart'>
        <h1 className='cart__title'>Cart</h1>
        <h2 className='cart__total'>Total cost {total.toFixed(2)} $</h2>
        {cart && (
          <ul className='cart__list'>
            {cart.map(item => (
              <CartItem 
                key={item.id} 
                item={item} 
                setTotal={setTotal}
                total={total}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I understand that the CartItem takes zero and overwrites the value, but how can I make it take the previous value as well?

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export const CartItem = ({item, total, setTotal, deleteItem, count, setCount}) => {
  const [itemCart, setItemCart] = useState(1)
  const [currentPrice, setCurrentPrice] = useState(item.price)

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotal(total + item.price)
  },[])

  function addProduct () {
    setTotal(total + item.price)
  }

  function removeProduct () {
    setTotal(total - item.price)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {itemCart ? (
        <li className='cart__item' key={item.id}>
        <img className='cart__img' src={item.img} alt="" />
        <div className='cart__name'>{item.title}</div>
        <div className='cart__price'>{currentPrice.toFixed(2)} $
          <button className='cart__btn' onClick={() => removeProduct(itemCart - 1)}>-</button>
            {itemCart}
          <button className='cart__btn' onClick={() => addProduct(itemCart + 1)}>+</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      ):(null)}
    </>
  )
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePNwM.png)

Comment: The approach looks clumsy, why you have `itemCart` state and does the `item` has info about price ? if so it `total` can be a derived state ...

Comment: @KcH i removed half of the code because all the code didn't fit, and question not about that

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the total in the state where you want it, together with useMemo hook it will recalculate every time cart changes:

```
 const total = useMemo(
    () =>
      cart.reduce(
        (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue.price,
        0
      ),
    [cart]
  );
```